# PHP does not redirect to contact HTML page?

Tags: php, forms, submit

This is my first time trying to write PHP. Sending the form input to my e-mail address works fine but after submitting the form it does not redirect to the `contact.htm` page! Why not?

```
<?php
  $name = $_REQUEST['textfield'];
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
  $message = $_REQUEST['textarea'];
  $mailto = "mail@example.nl";
  $from = "Sent by: ". $email. " ". $name . "\r\n";

  mail($mailto,"Contact form",$message,$from);
  include '/sub/folder/contact.htm';
?>
```

The `contact.htm` page is in the `/sub/folder/` and the same path is used in the PHP code above. Have I missed something? Can't I use subfolders? Does the file have to be in the site root main directory?

Comment: Check the PHP logs for errors.  Do you really have a folder called `/sub` in the root of your entire file system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

include is not working here. try this sample:

```
header("Location: http://YOUR_ADDRESS_HERE");
```

the address depends on your webService. localhost following any ports you've set

Comment: It works! Any reason for why include is not working?

Comment: include is not for html files. you can define some functions in another php file. and then use them in another file by including the file

Answer (score 0):

**Use header function instead of include -**

```
header("Location: /sub/folder/contact.htm");
```